# What needs to be considered when invoke threads inside a thread in Java or It should be avoided?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to use multithread, a thread pool in fact, for a large group of concurrent tasks. Unfortunately, the tool need to be used by the thread is also implemented by using thread and it is provided by third party. Is it safe to use thread inside thread? What should be considered or should it just be avoided totally.

Comment: Threads don't run "inside" of other threads. Threads run **parallel** to other threads, **inside of a common (parent) process.** The fact that you don't seem to understand, fundamentally, what a thread is, suggests that you should avoid using them before learning the basics.

Comment: Thanks guys, please see more details in the comment under next answer

Answer (score 2):

> What should be considered or it is just should be avoided totally.

A couple of things need to be considered:

- Threads are resource hungry.
- Thread creation is expensive.
- A thread pool ameliorates the cost of thread creation, but a bounded thread pool can cause fatal problems in certain cases.
- Threads are not good for solving divide and conquer problems, unless your algorithm uses the threads wisely.  (Don't use / waste threads where you should use recursion.)

The fatal problem I'm talking about is when threads recursively fork other threads and wait for them to finish.  If you use an unbounded thread pool you can end up with an unreasonable number of threads.  If you use a bounded thread pool, you can end up in a form of deadlock, where all threads are in use, and (possibly) all of them are blocked waiting to create more threads.

(It sounds like there is potential for that kind of thing in your scenario.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Stephen. The potential you mentioned acturally happened to me, probably deadlock. I will try to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Is it safe to use thread inside thread?***

If the library is thread safe, you should be able to use it from several threads.

> ***What should be considered or it is just should be avoided totally.***

As stated above, you should make sure all classes involved (the library classes, and your classes) are thread safe.

Personally, I try to avoid several threads entirely, *or* at least use as high-level constructs as possible, for instance by using classes from the `java.util.concurrent` package.

You may want to read up on

- [The Java™ Tutorials: Thread Pools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html), and
- The various implementations of [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Answer (score 1):

All threads are used "inside" other threads. (Except the ones you start with)

Perhaps you could explain your doubt in more detail.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. More details here:

Comment: Thanks, Peter. More details here: I am doing a flood ping for network discovery, the icmp ping package is implemented using thread, the concurrent ping I was trying to implement will use thread pool, for example Quartz package. Is it safe to do so? From test, the icmp ping some time just blocked and the memory consumed quite rapidly.

Comment: I don't see why it would have problems starting from a Quartz thread that it wouldn't have normally (it either works or it doesn't)  You could have a resource problem if your thread pool is not bounded.  The only way to fix that is to configure the library correctly or fix the code.  Flooding the network with pings might not be so useful.  Perhaps you can use broadcast pings.

Comment: Well, broadcasting ping is forbidened in my case. So have to ping one by one.

Comment: sending lots of pings is a common hacking technique.  If broadcast pings are forbidden perhaps you should either; not do it, or explain to whomever forbid it that you have a legitimate use case and forbidding it is far worse than the alternatives.

Comment: As part of the funtion I try to achieve is to monitor if around 10K devices are online or not among about 100k devices. The interval is about 10 second upwards. Since the devices I am interested is randomly embbeded in the 100k devices and in different/no-continous network segment, individual ping is prefered.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such concept of 'Thread inside a Thread' 
All the threads are invoked by some thread or another. (Except few obvious)
So they all kinda work in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I am getting some idea now